# activity started by "startActivityForResult" crashes when returning data

Tags: android

HI, I've made an application B called by app A with the startActivityForResult method.
When B try to return the result to A the application crashes and I get this error (by the way com.sistematica.carichispeciali.MobiWork is the application A, the one that calls B with startActivityForResult)

```
06-16 09:40:32.506: WARN/dalvikvm(744): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b390)
06-16 09:40:32.506: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.sistematica.carichispeciali/com.sistematica.carichispeciali.MobiWork}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3504)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3546)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:126)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1962)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at com.sistematica.carichispeciali.MobiWork.onActivityResult(MobiWork.java:96)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3868)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
06-16 09:40:32.526: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(744):     ... 11 more
```

this is how B returns the result

```
private void risultato(final String paper)
      {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setIcon(R.drawable.alt);
          builder.setTitle("risultato");
          builder.setMessage("è "+paper+" la targa?");
          builder.setPositiveButton("si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
              {
                dialog.dismiss();
                resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra("1", paper);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                finish();
              }
          });
          builder.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
              {
                 delRES();
              }
          });
          builder.show();
      };
```

and this is how A uses it (it should take the string returned and put it into an editText, never menaged to see if it really works since it crash before)

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
      switch(requestCode) { 
        case (1) : { 
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
          String newText = data.getStringExtra("1");
          m_plateField.setText(newText);
          } 
          break; 
        } 
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Step through with the debugger and check your MobiWork.java:96 it seams something there is null.

Comment: It seems like the application "A" they gave me has some issue. It actually doesnt declare properly the editText box, that's why it gave me the NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with this line:

```
String newText = data.getStringExtra("1");
```

Which might be returning null.

When you add an extra, prepend your application package:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("com.sistematica.carichispeciali.1", paper);
```

Then read it as:

```
String newText = data.getStringExtra("com.sistematica.carichispeciali.1");
```